# Choosing the correct "opensource" license for codes

Tags: design, programming-practices, open-source

In programming terms, what defines Open Source?

I am building a platform that I want to be open, to be used by other programmers in the context of running their own apps on it at the same time for companies on their public cloud.

The only restriction I want to have is if anyone, including companies, wants to make a profit of it, making it into a SaaS or "Software-as-a-Service" deployed in a public cloud, they must first acquire a commercial license.

Does this break the *spirit of opensource*? What are the options in terms of Licenses that will allow programmers/developers to take part in programming/shaping the platform while keeping it from being *SaaS*ified without a license to the organization that oversees the platform codes?

I've looked into [MongoDB SSPL](https://www.mongodb.com/licensing/server-side-public-license) and [MariaDB BSL](https://mariadb.com/bsl11/)

With the BSL more inclined to being Open-source and SSPL not being open-source.

Comment: A Google Search for "Open Source Definition" yields [this page](https://opensource.org/osd-annotated) as the first search result.

Comment: It might break the spirit but there are libraries which are dual-licensed as GPL and commercial, forcing users to choose between exposing their source code and paying for the license. You could license it using both Affero + commercial licenses. Sorry, I don’t have any examples at hand.

Answer (score 4):

> In programming terms, what defines Open Source?

With respect to licensing, the most frequently referenced definitions are the [Open Source Initiative's (OSI) Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd-annotated) or the [Free Software Foundation's (FSF) Free Software Definition](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html).

> The only restriction I want to have is if anyone, including companies, wants to make a profit of it, making it into a SaaS or "Software-as-a-Service" deployed in a public cloud, they must first acquire a commercial license.

What you describe is not an open source license and would likely run afoul of requirements in both the OSI definition as well as the FSF definition. Although you can have a commercial product that is also released under an open source license, an open source license would not restrict free distribution of the source code or derived works. An open source license cannot prevent commercial use.

There are licenses that are designed to make it harder for people to profit off of open source. One good example is the [Affero General Public License](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.en.html). This license requires that software accessed over a network (such as in the case of a SAAS application) would have any corresponding source code available to end users. So if someone did take your software and created a SAAS application, they would have to release the code and any of their modifications to users.

Dual-licensing is also a way around this. For example, an enterprise customer may want to host the SAAS application and not release any modifications they make. Software can be available under two or more licenses. In exchange for payment, the software can be released to a customer under a different open source license or even a custom license that would not require them to release the source code to their clients.

Comment: I see, so dual licensing is the best option. However, does it not contradict the first argument with opensource (you) "cannot prevent commercial use."? Also, the AGPL seems to be something that may fit, but does it also restrict the original author from creating a SAAS based on the opensource code? Or if I rethink of it,with AGPL I can make a SAAS of my original work but also make it open source. Any other entity that will use will will have to do the same (including derivatives)?

Comment: @xybrek Dual-licensing isn't a contradiction. The open source license meets all of the criteria of the OSI and/or FSF (depending on the license). The commercial license does not need to meet that criteria. If your project was under the AGPL, you couldn't prevent someone from creating a SAAS application, but you would force them into releasing any modifications that they make to any end users. Assuming you hold the copyright (and don't have any other contributors), you can do whatever you want.

Comment: My intention is to have more contributors to the project and build a community around it. So it must be that Dual-licensing is the option.

Comment: @xybrek, if you want to distribute the software under a license that is potentially different from the terms under which contributors submit their contribution, you should look into having a [Contributor License Agreement](http://oss-watch.ac.uk/resources/cla). It will save you a lot of legal hassle if you set it up correctly from the beginning.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau currently the codebase of the platform is solely from me, and other contributors that I hired/paid. The code is still in private repository and planning to move it into Public/Open source so the platform can get fixes and contributions of the community. With what you mentioned do I need to put the CLA in a separate License text file in the source code and also in the code headers? What is the general rule?

Comment: @ThomasOwens also for dual licensing, where to put the license text for the dual license? I mean, usually, in my codes hosted in GitHub there's a license header in source codes ad a LICENSE.txt file, which contains the license which is either Apache or GPL. For dual license what would be the case?

Comment: @xybrek These are separate questions that deserve their own answers. But I'd recommend searching first, not only here, but on [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) and [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) as well - you may find answers to these questions already.

Comment: @xybrek, a CLA is a contract that contributors must sign/agree to, which gives you the right to use contributions under a different license. That can't be dealt with in a License text file or a comment block in the code.